# PYTHON - How to change one character in many file names within a directory

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a large directory containing image files and need to change one character within the name of each file name. The character is in the same place in each file name (17). I think I need to use the 'replace' string function but as I am very new to Python I am not sure how to write this in a script (I work in GIS and have just started learning Python). Any help would be greatly appreciated. The character I need to change is the '1' after Nepal_Landscape_S'in the file name *Nepal_Landscape_S1_LayerStacked_IM9_T44RQR_stack4.tif* I simply need to change this to 2, like: *Nepal_Landscape_S2_LayerStacked_IM9_T44RQR_stack4.tif*

Comment: what's wrong with

`s = 'Nepal_Landscape_S1_LayerStacked_IM9_T44RQR_stack4.tif'`

`s = s.replace('1', '2')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the string `replace` method as you suspect along with `os.rename`.

```
import os
files = os.listdir("path/to/files")
for src in files:
    dst = src.replace('S1', 'S2')
    os.rename(src, dst)
```

If you are able to use your shell for this type of task, there may be simpler solutions, like the `rename` bash command: `rename S1 S2 *S1*`