# How to multiplely modify one piece of the file name in python

Tags: python, rename, filenames

New learner. I have several txt files in a folder. I need to change the 'April' into 'APR'.

`12 April 2019 Nmae's something Something.txt`

`13 April 2019 World's - as Countr something.txt`

`14 April 2019 Name and location.txt`

`15 APR 2019 Name then location,for something.txt`

So it looks like this

`12 APR 2019 Nmae's something Something.txt`

`13 APR 2019 World's - as Countr something.txt`

`14 APR 2019 Name and location.txt`

`15 APR 2019 Name then location,for something.txt`

Here are links with the similar ones, but each of them are slightly different.

[Python - Replace multiple characters in one file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171098/python-replace-multiple-characters-in-one-file-name)

[CHange multiple file name python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65267104/change-multiple-file-name-python)

[PYTHON - How to change one character in many file names within a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37053331/python-how-to-change-one-character-in-many-file-names-within-a-directory)

[How to change multiple filenames in a directory using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34960343/how-to-change-multiple-filenames-in-a-directory-using-python#34960641)

I tried this:

```
import os
files = os.listdir('/home/runner/Final/foldername')
   for f in files:
newname = f.replace('April', 'APR')
os.rename(f, newname)
```

But nothing changed, can I get some guide?

Comment: This might be due to your working directory. When you call `os.rename(f, ...)` it needs to know where `f` is. Giving a full path via `os.path.join('/home/runner/Final/foldername', f)` might help. I'm not sure if you then need to also use `os.path.join('/home/runner/Final/foldername', newname)` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `f` is just the filename, not the full path, so your command  `os.rename(f, newname)` would rename a file named `f` in the current working directory, not the target directory. Also, you'd attempt to rename every file instead of just the ones that actually change.

Here's something a bit better:

```
from pathlib import Path


for f in Path('/home/runner/Final/foldername').glob('*'):
    if f.is_file():
        new_name = f.name.replace('April', 'APR')
        if new_name != f.name:
            f.rename(Path('/home/runner/Final/foldername') / new_name)
```

It also checks if something that was found is actually a file (otherwise, it would include directories, and it appears you don't want to rename those).

Note that, in the most recent version of Python, this also works:

```
for f in Path('/home/runner/Final/foldername').glob('*'):
    if f.is_file():
        if (new_name := f.name.replace('April', 'APR')) != f.name:
            f.rename(Path('/home/runner/Final/foldername') / new_name)
```

And to avoid continually reconstructing a `Path` object:

```
folder = Path('/home/runner/Final/foldername')

for f in folder .glob('*'):
    if f.is_file():
        if (new_name := f.name.replace('April', 'APR')) != f.name:
            f.rename(folder / new_name)
```